# Razor/ MVC - Javascript Function with params rendered incorrectly

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am calling the following in a partial view;

```
 @Html.RadioButton("answers", @a.Item1, new { @OnClick = @Html.Raw(string.Format("AnswerSelected('{0}','{1}');", @a.Item2, @a.Item1)) })@a.Item2
```

This produces the following on teh page;

```
<input OnClick="AnswerSelected(&#39;Yes&#39;,&#39;2&#39;);" id="answers" name="answers" type="radio" value="2" />Yes
```

Removing the @Html.Raw makes no difference.

So its encoding the ' around the parameters. How do I stop this, or am I approaching the problem incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you model itself is returning a string with item1 value as "'Yes'".

This is the only case when Html.Raw fails as the string in itself might have been escaped by String.Format.

You could try :

```
@Html.RadioButton("answers", @a.Item1, new { @OnClick = "AnswerSelected(" + @Html.Raw(@a.Item2) + "," +  @Html.Raw(@a.Item1) + ")"})@a.Item2
```

If this doesnt work, try a simple replace

```
replace(/&#39;/g, "'")
```

Comment: No, it still gives me 

    OnClick="AnswerSelected(&#39;Yes&#39;,&#39;2&#39;);"

Comment: No, nor does string.Concat(..). Something is converting the ' to &#39 as they get rendered..